# Python class doesn't see second object in list(attribute)

Tags: python, oop

I want to code movie classification class, which can find (based on some criterias), add and print movies.

Here is my code:

```
class Movie:
    def __init__(self,name,director,year,location):
        self.name = name
        self.director = director
        self.year = year
        self.location = location
        self.information = {'name':self.name,'director':self.director,'year':self.year,'location':self.location}

    def get_name(self):
        return self.name

    def get_director(self):
        return self.director

    def get_year(self):
        return self.year

    def get_location(self):
        return self.location 

    def get_information(self):
        return self.information

    def __str__(self):
        return f"Name = {self.name},director = {self.director},year = {self.year},location = {self.location}"

class Classification:
    def __init__(self):
        self.movie_list = []

    def length(self):
        return len(self.movie_list)

    def __getitem__(self,key):
        if isinstance(self.movie_list,slice):
            return self.movie_list[key]

    def add_movie(self,movie):
        self.movie_list.append(movie)              

    def print_movie(self):
        for movie in self.movie_list:
            print(movie)

    def find_movie(self,**kwargs):
        check_list = []
        for movie in self.movie_list:
            for name,value in kwargs.items():
                if movie.get_information()[name] == value:
                    check_list.append(True)
                else:
                    check_list.append(False)     
            if all(item == True for item in check_list):
                print(movie)
        check_list.clear()
```

Here i have a class `Movie` and `Classification`; `Classification` has only 1 attribute, which is a list of movies. But i have two problems:

```
a = Movie('Matrix','Dan Yefimov','1999','New York')
b = Movie('Legend','Mak Markus','2005','Kiev')
clasif = Classification()
clasif.add_movie(a)
clasif.add_movie(b)
clasif.find_movie(location = 'New York')
```

1. `find_movie()` works for the first movie (`a` in our case) in the list. But for the second one it prints nothing, even when I enter correct parameters for a search.
2. Slicing doesn't work. There is no error message, it just prints nothing.

Can you help me with my problems?

P.S I would like also to hear some general advices about improving of my code.

Comment: For starters, stop writing getters.

Comment: `check_list.clear()`  should be inside the `for` loop.

Comment: `isinstance(self.movie_list,slice)` will always be `False`.  `movie_list` is always a `list`.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga thank you for the answer!  Can you explain why?

Comment: Because it is not the Pythonic way of doing things. If you are coming from a language like Java, read this: https://www.python-course.eu/python3_properties.php

Comment: @PatrickHaugh thank you for the answer! Do you have maybe some other remarks about the code? Maybe there is a possibility to improve smth?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By removing the unnecessary methods, we can shorten the code considerably.  We can also just pass `__getitem__` through to the list.   I would also use `__len__` over defining a `length` method.

```
class Movie:
    def __init__(self,name,director,year,location):
        self.name = name
        self.director = director
        self.year = year
        self.location = location
    def __str__(self):
        return f"Name = {self.name},director = {self.director},year = {self.year},location = {self.location}"

class Classification:
    def __init__(self):
        self.movie_list = []    
    def __len__(self):  # __len__ lets you do len(classif)
        return len(self.movie_list)    
    def __getitem__(self,key):
        return self.movie_list[key]    
    def add_movie(self,movie):
        self.movie_list.append(movie)                  
    def print_movie(self):
        for movie in self.movie_list:
            print(movie)       
    def find_movie(self,**kwargs):
        for movie in self.movie_list:
            if all(hasattr(movie, k) and getattr(movie, k) == v for k, v in kwargs.items()):
                print(movie)
```

Comment: Thank yo ufor your answer? But can we use hust getattr function in the find_movie method?

Comment: @DY92 I'm afraid I don't understand your question.  I use `hasattr` here so that incorrectly entered attribute names don't cause an error.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a version of your code will a little less code:

```
class Movie:
    ATTRIBUTES = ('name', 'director', 'year', 'location')

    def __init__(self, name, director, year, location):
        self.name = name
        self.director = director
        self.year = year
        self.location = location

    def __str__(self):
        return ', '.join(
            '{} = {}'.format(attr_name, getattr(self, attr_name))
            for attr_name in self.ATTRIBUTES)


class Classification:
    def __init__(self):
        self.movie_list = []

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.movie_list)

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return self.movie_list[key]

    def add_movie(self, movie):
        self.movie_list.append(movie)

    def print_movies(self):
        for movie in self.movie_list:
            print(movie)

    def find_movies(self, **kwargs):
        for movie in self.movie_list:
            do_print = True
            for attr_name, attr_value in kwargs.items():
                if attr_name in Movie.ATTRIBUTES:
                    if getattr(movie, attr_name) != attr_value:
                        do_print = False
            if do_print:
                print(movie)
```

I added a class attribute called `ATTRIBUTES` to `Movie`; this is used in `Movie.__str__()` and also in `Classification.find_movies()`. It is a suggestion to avoid repeating the attributes a lot in the code.

In the method `Classification.find_movies()` I check that it is a valid attribute before I compare it to the movie instance. Invalid parameters are ignored, but you could change the code so that invalid parameters automatically cause the movies to not be printed (all will be excluded).